# writing to file from cython

Tags: python, cython

By profiling, I've determined that about 60% of my program's time is spent in writing to file, in the one line:

```
fout.write('%d\t%d\n' % (i, j))
```

Here i and j are integers. Two questions: would implementing this in Cython give me a significant speed gain, and how would I implement it in Cython? I'm having trouble finding examples of writing to files from Cython.

Regarding the last point, this line occurs in a function that is called by the rest of my program very often to dump output to a file, so I'd like to leave the file open between function calls, and pass in a file object rather than reopening the file in each call.

Comment: String formatting: `tmp = '%d\t%d\n' % (i, j)` and writing to file `fout.write(tmp)` are two separate statements. You may need to re-profile.

Comment: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4961701/1797098)

Comment: @AlexGittens did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a significant performance gain by sending to your hard drive a compacted amount of data, which can be achieved using [`numpy.savez_compressed()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html), or writting in binary format:

```
with open('name.output', 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(data)
```

Cython uses the same functions to write files that Python does, accessed through the Python API, and therefore it should not make it faster.

Comment: I have a [Cython post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944883/verifying-compatibility-in-compiling-extension-types-and-using-them-with-cdef) you may be able to provide insight on.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out... Just had a quick look

Comment: An update has been made outlining the bulk that needed resolving. Thank you anyway.