# Writing the content of a list on a text file

Tags: python, text

I want to write the contents of lists on a text file.
The way I currently do it is the following:

```
for k in li:
    outp.write(str(k))
out.write('\n')
```

however, this is taking a long time to run (I have tens of millions of lines)

Is there any faster way?

**Sample Lines**

The lists are from a sparse matrix so there are plenty of zeros. The non null elements are ones only

eg of such a list: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]

The numbers are separated by tabs

Comment: Does it have to be human readable? i.e. What uses the file afterwards?

Comment: @doctorlove yes in a text file read

Comment: Please post a couple of sample lines in your lists. We might be able to exploit some properties of the data

Comment: What does "in a text file read " mean? If a machine reads it, binary (eg pickle) might be quicker. And then you don't need to make it a string first.

Comment: @doctorlove no I write it in a text file and this text file has to be read by a human. Also, I need strings because the person who's gonna use it needs it in this format

Comment: @bigTree Then maybe this entry could be interesting to you: [Speed up writing to files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961589/speed-up-writing-to-files). Writing to the disk is slow. There is not a golden rule you can use to speed it up. But maybe you find some optimizations there...

Comment: Actually the list @MathiasGhys gave answers my question. I'll close this post thans

Comment: I wonder if it would be faster for you to save the coordinates of the `1`s, rather than the entire matrix. You could easily recreate it when you read it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if storing the coordinates of the `1`s would yield desired speedups, as you mention that this is a sparse matrix. Consider the following:

Write to file:

```
def writeMatrix(matrix):
    ones = [[i for i,num in row if num==1] for row in matrix]
    with open('path/to/file', 'w') as outfile:
        for row in ones:
            outfile.write(' '.join(str(i) for i in row))
            outfile.write('\n')
```

Read from file:

```
def readMatrix(infilepath, width):
    answer = []
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            row = [None]*width
            for i in set(int(i) for i in line.split()):
                row[i] = 1
            answer.append(row)
    return answer
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a pretty decent speed up by only writing once and leaving out all of those manual casts:

```
out.write('\n'.join(li))
```

There's probably further optimizations, but really you should look at a binary-based filed format for something where you have such a big array.

Specifically [marshal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html) seems like a great fit, but there are faster things out there.

Comment: it output an error saying "Type Error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found"