# How to write a list of strings and ints to file efficiently

Tags: python, list, file

I've got a list, containing lists of strings and ints, for example:

`l = [['+1', 12, 13, 14], ['+1', 13, 14, 15]]`

I need to write this list into a file, every sub-list in a separate row.

I did it like this:

`f.writelines(['%s ' % item for item in l])`

It works fine. However, the lists I'm using are very big, so this code runs *extremely* slowly. Is there a faster alternative?

Comment: If I recall correctly, I think the limiting factor is your actual hardware writing speed, not Python, so you may not need to worry about that

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961589/speed-up-writing-to-files

Answer (score 4):

Did you already try just writing the lines without "sub-looping" through each element?

```
for i in l:
    f.write("%s %d %d %d\n" % tuple(i))
```

Minimizing the number of independent `write` events is going to give you the best speed increase.

If your file is small enough to fit in memory, you could build up the output string in a loop and then just use one `write` operation to output it.

*(Note, see below for time test of generating output string)*

A quick way to make one output string for the whole file (this assumes you don't want the `[]` -- add them to the string if you do):

```
outstring = "\n".join(["%s %d %d %d" % tuple(i) for i in l])
f.write(outstring)
```

If it is too large for that, you could build up the string chunk by chunk (for example, 10000 items at a time) and write them in batches.

Finally, this almost looks like `json` format, so if you are trying to create a `json` file, you could do:

```
import json
json.dumps(l)
```

EDIT: You don't need `json` at all, just use `str(mylist)` for this... See implementation below.

---

LATER:

I did some timing on generating the output string.

```
outstr = str(mylist)[1:-1].replace("], ","]\n").replace(",","")
```

is three times faster than:

```
outstr = "\n".join(["%s %d %d %d" % tuple(i) for i in mylist])
```

Comment: Hi @beroe, thanks for your reply. My sublists have different lengths, so I'm not sure how to use your first solution? (and no, it's not json format, I'm creating files similar to CSVs).

Comment: Do you want the brackets in your output? I think the lower json example (with `replace`) could be made to work. Generating a single output string and one `write` is key, even if you use your original list comprehension. Just append to a string there instead of writing to the file.

Comment: I got rid of the json -- `str` works just as well: `outstr = str(mylist)[1:-1].replace("], ","]\n").replace(",","")` You can tailor the `.replace` however you want your final string formatted.

Answer (score 2):

When you use list comprehension like this:

```
["%s " % item for item in l]
```

Python creates a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). So the number of items in `l` (as you well said) is not the problem. But, almost always, better performance comes with more code.

My point: Use a generator for print each element of the row too. That way you dont have to load the entire list to memory.

Try this:

```
l = [['+1', 12, 13, 14], ['+1', 13, 14, 15]]

f = open("your_file.txt", 'w')

for item in l:
    f.write('[')
    for elem in item[:-1]:
        f.write("{}, ".format(elem))
    f.write("{}".format(item[-1]))
    f.write(']\n')
```

This must, at least, consume less memory.