# Batch writes in excel using Python PyExcelerate

Tags: python, export-to-excel, pyexcelerate

I am trying to speed up the process of writing data to an excel file using python in my code.
The PyExcelerate module has a good benchmark in terms of writing bulk data to files compared to other python modules.

- Dimensions:
  Rows = 10000
  Cols = 50
- Times:

  - pyexcelerate          :  10.11
  - xlwt                  :  15.67
  - xlsxwriter (optimised):  19.70
  - xlsxwriter            :  23.50
  - openpyxl   (optimised):  95.82
  - openpyxl              :  95.90

Also, writing data in batches improves the time taken to write furthermore.
See link below.

[Speed up writing to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961589/speed-up-writing-to-files[link])

Now, what I am trying to do is add data to a list as and when it is computed, and when the list size is equal to 500 or when 500 rows of data have been computed, write to the file.

`wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.new_sheet("test")
ws.range("B2", "C3").value = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
wb.save("output.xlsx")`

Is there a way that we could append the data for 500 rows in a batch?

Comment: If you install lxml then you'll get better results with openpyxl. As long as you're working with purely numerical data, PyExcelerate is probably the fastest module. Adding comfort usually comes with a performance cost but you might want to look at the `write_row()` method of xlsxwriter.

Comment: Thanks this is almost the solution that I required.
I now just want to write the data in Batches of 500 using the `write_row()`

Answer (score 1):

Use PyExcelerate its pretty fast then write_row from xlsxwriter  and append from openpyxl .Refer
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyExcelerate