# Python, efficient way of generating copies the same yaml with only one field changed?

Tags: python, parsing, yaml

Let's say I am given a yaml file called "label.yaml"

```
id: 1
color: red
toy: car
```

I want to make 10000 copies of this file with `id` being the ONLY value that changes and all it has to do is change incrementally.

```
id: 1
color: red
toy: car
```

```
id: 2
color: red
toy: car
```

```
id: 3
color: red
toy: car
```

...
And so on...

Something I've tried:

```
import yaml

with open("data.yaml") as f:
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)


for i in range(1,100001):
    data["id"] = i

    with open(f"data-{i}.yaml", "w+") as f:
        yaml.dump(data, f)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple trick I might suggest, is instead of calling `yaml.dump` or `yaml.load`, you can just have a string with the YAML contents, do string replacement, and write the string contents to file directly, without the `yaml` library.

The example below uses `str.format` to format a template string with the local variable `i` in each loop iteration.

```py
file_template = """
id: {}
color: red
toy: car
""".strip()

for i in range(1,100001):
    file_contents = file_template.format(i)

    with open(f"data-{i}.yaml", "w") as f:
        f.write(file_contents)
```

---

NB: Per [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961589/speed-up-writing-to-files), there doesn't seem to be a way to speed up disk IO using `open` unfortunately. I feel as if this is likely the most optimized version that is possible - note that the long execution times you may notice are mainly because of disk I/O, which is slow by nature.