How can I speed up the processing of my nested for loops for a giant 3D numpy array?
I created a very large 3D numpy array called tr_mat. The shape of tr_mat is:
tr_mat.shape
(1024, 536, 21073)

Info on the 3D numpy array: First and before going into the actual code, I would like to clarify what I am attempting to do. As can be seen from tr_mat.shape, the 3D numpy array contains numeric values in 1024 rows and 536 columns. That is, we have 536 * 1024 = 548864 values in each of the 21073 matrices.
Conceptual background about my task:
Each of the 21073 2D numpy arrays within the 3D numpy array contains grayscaled pixel values from an image. The 3D numpy array tr_mat is already transposed, because I would like to construct a time-series based on identical pixel positions across all 21073 matrices. Finally, I would like to individually save each of the resulting 548864 time-series in a .1D textfile. (Hence, I would end up with saving 548864 .1D textfiles.)
The relevant part of the code:
tr_mat = frame_mat.transpose() # the tranposed 3D numpy array
# Save
rangeh = range(0, 1024)
for row, row_n_l in zip(tr_mat, rangeh): # row = pixel row of the 2D image
        for ts_pixel, row_n in zip(row, rangeh): # ts_pixel = the pixel time-series across the 3D array (across the single 2D arrays)
        # Save
        with open(f"/volumes/.../TS_Row{row_n_l}_Pixel{row_n}.1D", "w") as file:
                for i in ts_pixel: file.write(f"{i}\n") # Save each time-series value per row

Question: Could you provide me some tips how to modify my code in order to speed it up? I wrapped tqdm around the first for loop to check how fast the nested loop is processed, and it took around 20 minutes to reach ~120 of 536 rows. Also, it seems to me that the loop gets slower and slower as the iterations go up.
A reproducible code with random generated values can be found in the following: Please only change the output directory
import numpy as np
tr_mat = np.random.random((1024, 536, 21073))

rangeh = range(0, 1024)
for row, row_n_l in zip(tr_mat, rangeh):
    for ts_pixel, row_n in zip(row, rangeh):
        # Save
        with open("/volumes/../TS_Row{row_n_l}_Pixel{row_n}.1D", "w") as file: # Please adjust the output directory
            for i in ts_pixel: file.write(f"{i}\n")


I will say that the bottleneck here is undoubtedly the IO. Is this an operation you need to do once and then never again, or something you need to run frequently? If it's the former, I would set it to run overnight and not think about it again. If it's the latter, I would re-consider what you're doing. Does each one really need to be a separate file, thus saving ~550,000 individual files to the disk? Surely you'll be re-loading these into a different program afterwards. Perhaps one (or a few) big files containing many, indexed time series each will be better.

Could you provide some minimal, reproducible example?

Thanks. I added a reproducible code that generates random values to fill up the 3D array.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961589/speed-up-writing-to-files may have some tips for you to consider

I agree with stelioslogothetis comment, reconsider what you are doing. Save in different format, less larger files, maybe also with some compression involved.
If you stick to your plan this code is significantly (2-3x) faster:
save_path = f"/volumes/../TS_Row{row_n_l}_Pixel{row_n}.1D"
with open(save_path, "w") as file:
    big_string = '\n'.join([str(item) for item in ts_pixel])
    # you may want to add newline char "\n" at the end, the only difference
    file.write(big_string)

And if you want big savings of time just use np.save, its like 100x faster than your code
np.save(save_path, ts_pixel)
# possible saving some space using float instead of double:
np.save(save_path, ts_pixel.astype(np.float32))


Thank you! I followed the advice by stelioslogothetis. I saved chunks of data (300 time-series into one file) instead of saving each time-series into a single file. This massively speeded up the process. And it is good to know about np.save, I didn't come across it yet. So it is good to know for future codes that np.save is faster than saving via with open.
